# How to use gherkin-official

Tags: python, pip, gherkin

I am trying to use python to parse .feature files that are in gherkin syntax.

I ran `pip install gherkin-official`.

I can now run `import gherkin` but the object has no methods on it. I don't know how to use it and I can't find any documentation. How can I use this module to parse a file with its contents in gherkin syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at the tests to see how it can be used: https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin-python/blob/master/test/gherkin_test.py

Looks like the basics start by importing:

```
from gherkin.token_scanner import TokenScanner
from gherkin.parser import Parser
```

and then using it:

```
parser = Parser()
feature_file = parser.parse(TokenScanner("Feature: Foo"))
```